# How can I round values to the next .5 for every number where decimal part is greater than 0 using c#:

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I round up values like this using c#:

```
1.1 => 1.5

2.0 => 2.0

2.1 => 2.5

1.9 => 1.5

7.7 => 7.5
```

I always want value to be in `0.5` or `0.0`

Comment: multiply it by 2 than round it than divide again

Comment: Didn't get the logic behind 1.1=1.5 and 7.7=7.5

Comment: As it looks like homework I won't give you complete recipe just a clue: "Multiply by 2".

Comment: You're going to need to roll your own function for this one if you don't want whole numbers.  Take @cerkiewny 's advice and write a method.

Comment: You really want to round up if the value is between .0 and .49 and round off if the value is between .5 and .99? Btw, instead of `like this` try to describe your requirement in the title.

Comment: Did you try any code?

Comment: The question is bad expressed, it's not round up only, he want to round to .5 if the number is greater than .0

Comment: we had long discussion here guys but looks like @Hanu not replying anything..

Answer (score 2):

```
if(no-(int)no!=0.0)
    no=(int)no+0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = 1.1;
if (d != Math.Floor(d)) d = Math.Floor(d) + 0.5;
```

Please try this and put your all values to check.

Hope it works!